# i need help getting seed = os.clock to output a integer

Tags: random, lua

I am trying to get a random number generation but keep getting this syntax.

```
lua5.3: Main.lua:3: bad argument #1 to 'random' (number has no integer representation)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'math.random'
    Main.lua:3: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

I tried to use this to get a random number but it doesn`t have a integer representation.

```
seed = os.clock()
print(seed)
e = math.random(seed)
print(e)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be assuming Lua 5.4. Quoting the reference manual:

> ##### [`math.randomseed ([x [, y]])`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-math.randomseed)
>
> When called with at least one argument, the integer parameters x and y are joined into a 128-bit seed that is used to reinitialize the pseudo-random generator; equal seeds produce equal sequences of numbers. The default for y is zero.
>
> When called with no arguments, Lua generates a seed with a weak attempt for randomness.
>
> This function returns the two seed components that were effectively used, so that setting them again repeats the sequence.
>
> To ensure a required level of randomness to the initial state (or contrarily, to have a deterministic sequence, for instance when debugging a program), you should call math.randomseed with explicit arguments.
>
> ##### [`math.random ([m [, n]])`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-math.random)
>
> When called without arguments, returns a pseudo-random float with uniform distribution in the range [0,1). When called with two integers m and n, math.random returns a pseudo-random integer with uniform distribution in the range [m, n]. The call math.random(n), for a positive n, is equivalent to math.random(1,n). The call math.random(0) produces an integer with all bits (pseudo)random.
>
> ##### [`os.clock()`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-os.clock)
>
> Returns an approximation of the amount in seconds of CPU time used by the program, as returned by the underlying ISO C function clock.

So `os.clock()` returns a fractional value like `0.002814`; it is not rounded/floored to seconds. `math.random` expects an integer like `42` and thus errors as you don't provide an integer, but rather a fractional number.

`math.random` also doesn't expect a "seed"; it expects a range. Use `math.randomseed` to seed `math.random`. As the docs tell you, if you don't care about the "randomness" of the seed, just call `math.randomseed()` without arguments.

You probably want to use `os.time()` for seeding. `os.time()` produces an integer (typically the seconds since the UNIX epoch). The caveat is that invocations during the same second will use the same seed.